# WiFi на ноуте с Windows 10 перестал подключаться к определённому SSID

Tags: windows-10, wifi

Сам адаптер WiFi работает - видит сети и может к ним подключаться, кроме одного SSID, с которым он недавно без проблем работал, и к которому легко подключаются и работают другие устройства.
Выполняется попытка подключения и сброс - "не удаётся подключиться к данной сети" без каких либо деталей. Пароли сети не менялись. В логах маршрутизатора не фиксируется даже попытка подключения от этого устройства. Средство устранения неполадок Windows ничего не видит. Сброс сети не помог.

Как в Win10 получить более подробную информацию о процессе подключения к беспроводной сети и возникающем в процессе сбое?
Можно ли при помощи например Wireshark отследить сам процесс установки беспроводного соединения?

[UPDATE]

Заработало после смены на роутере диапазона с "n" на "g" и обратно.
С чем связан сбой в Windows так и не ясно.